# VisualStudio2022でeccodes-2.30.0-Sourceをビルド出来ない

Tags: python3, c++, visual-studio

[eccodes-2.30.0-Source](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/Releases) のsrcディレクトリには.ccファイルが格納されており、これをビルドしたいと考えた。

手順：
eccodes-2.30.0-Source\windows\msvc\grib_api.slnを右クリックしてVisual Studio 2022を開く。ソリューション'grib_api'プロジェクトを右クリックしてソリューションのビルドを選択したが、以下の様なエラーが多発します。.cファイルを探していて.ccファイルを認識しないようです。

```
エラー C1083   ソース ファイルを開けません。'..\..\..\src\action.c':No such file or directory    grib_api_lib    C:\Users\go_ta\Downloads\eccodes-2.30.0-Source\windows\msvc\grib_api_lib\c1 1
```

2.27.1の場合はsrcファイルの中身が.cファイルなので同じ手順で無事にビルドできます。`conda install pygrib` でpygribをインストールしたのちdefinitionsディレクトリをanacondaにセットして、当面問題なくpygribを利用できています。pipを利用しない場合はビルドにこだわる必要が無いので気にしなくても良いかもしれませんが、何となくスッキリしません。

VisualStudioにもC++環境にも詳しくないのでどうすればよいのか全く見当がつきません。.ccファイルを.cにコピーして実行すると当然ながら記述方法の違いからエラーとなります。これを解決する方法がありましたら、ご教示ください。

Comment: こんな記事 [Important changes in new release of ecCodes 2.29.0: Dropping python2 interface, compiling with a C++ compiler](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=315571816) があるので、`windows/msvc`フォルダの内容は更新されていないのでは？ ちなみに[ecCodes installationのMicrosoft Windows](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/ecCodes+installation#ecCodesinstallation-MicrosoftWindows)には、翻訳すると`注: Windows は、ECMWF での技術的な作業に使用されるプラットフォームではありません。 したがって、Linux などの他のプラットフォームと同じようにこのプラットフォームをサポートすることはできません。 運用上の使用には、Linux を使用することを強くお勧めします。`と書かれています。

Comment: 試しにsayuriさんの回答の作業(GitHubページの[INSTALLATION](https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes#installation)と同等と思われる)をするか、`.ccファイルを.cにコピー`するのではなく、`.vcxproj`ファイルを直接編集して、`<ClCompile Include="..\..\..\src\action.c" />`となっている所の`.c`を`.cc`に(他のファイル指定も含めて)全て書き変えてみるのはどうでしょう？

Comment: Kunifさん、ありがとうございました。
ご指摘の「.c->.cc」への書き換えでファイルが存在しないエラーは解消しました。
これで、一歩前進です。

Comment: Kunifさん、

昨日ファイルエラーは解消しましたが、未解決シンボル'grib_accessor_class_data_run_length_packing'が課題として残りました。

本日当該シンボルのソースをgrib_api_lib.vcxprojに追加することでビルドに成功しました。

Comment: それはおめでとうございます。情報共有のために作業の詳細を自己回答してみてください。それから内容に問題無さそうなら本体のリポジトリにPullRequestを出してみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。

#### 現象

- ダウンロードしてLhaplusで解凍
- eccodes-2.30.0-Sourceのsrcディレクトリにあるeccodes_versions.h.in をeccodes_versions.hとしてコピーし＠の部分をバージョンに合わせて変更（Kunifsiの指摘により追記）
- eccodes-2.30.0-Sourceのwindows\msvc\grib_api.slnを右クリックしアプリ選択でVisual Studio 2022を選択。
- プロジェクトの再ターゲット画面でOKを選択
- ソリューションタブで'grib_api'を右クリックしてソリューションのビルドを選択すると、以下のエラーが多発する
- エラー C1083 ソース ファイルを開けません。'......\src\action.c':No such file or directory grib_api_lib C:\Users\go_ta\Downloads\eccodes-2.30.0-Source\windows\msvc\grib_api_lib\c1 1
- srcディレクトリにあるソースは.cc拡張子なのにエラーメッセージでは.c拡張子を探しに行っている。

#### 解決手順

- .vcxprojに記述されたソースファイルの拡張子を変更してみればと言う回答（Kunif氏）を参考に、すべての.vcxproj内の.c拡張子を全て.cc拡張子に変更。
- 再度grib_api.slnを右クリックしアプリ選択でVisual Studio 2022を選択。
- ソリューションタブを右クリックしてソリューションのビルドを選択すると上記のファイルエラーは解消する。
- 新たな問題として'grib_accessor_class_data_run_length_packing'が未解決シンボルと表示される。
- srcディレクトリには未解決シンボルのソースファイルが存在するので、記入漏れと判断してgrib_api_lib.vcxproj内に追加する。
- 再度grib_api.slnを右クリックしアプリ選択でVisual Studio 2022を選択。
- ソリューションタブを右クリックしてソリューションのビルドを選択するエラーは解消してビルドが正常終了する。

#### 感想

- ビルドを実行するときに対象を指定する仕組みを理解していなかったことが原因。
- 指摘された.xprojファイルに対象ソースファイルが指定されているので拡張子変更が必要。
- 未解決シンボルは指定が足りないことが原因と想定されるので対象を確認して、適切な場所に追加すれば問題なく稼働することを理解した。

Comment: 現象または解決手順のところに、`srcフォルダのeccodes_versions.h.in をコピーして、eccodes_versions.h を作成し、その中の版数情報を設定する。`を追加する必要があるのでは？ [Windows の pip で Pygrib をインストールする](https://log.mkuriki.com/pygrib-install-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

どのような手順を実施したのか質問文に書かれていないのでわかりませんが、その手順が間違っていたと推測されます。 [`.appveyor.yml`](https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes/blob/master/.appveyor.yml)を参考にするといいでしょう。概ね次のようになっていて、

```
build_script:
  - cmd: cd %ECCODES_SRC%
  - cmd: mkdir build && cd build
  - cmd: cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ^
               -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%INSTALL_DIR% ^
               -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
               -D ENABLE_FORTRAN=0 ^
               -D ENABLE_NETCDF=1 ^
               -D ENABLE_JPG=1 ^
               -D ENABLE_AEC=0 ^
               -D IEEE_LE=1 ^
               -D ENABLE_MEMFS=1 ^
               -D ENABLE_EXTRA_TESTS=ON ^
               -D WINDOWS_TESTING_BASHRC=%WINDOWS_TESTING_BASHRC% ^
               ..
  - cmd: nmake
  - cmd: ctest --output-on-failure
  - cmd: nmake install
```

辺りの`- cmd:` を取り除いた部分を実行してください。

Answer (score 0):

kunif さんがコメント欄で言及している通り、公式サイトのマニュアルには "Windows には対応していない" とあるので、Linux 環境を用意した方が近道だと思います。

参考までに、"eccodes visual studio" で検索してみると非公式な Windows 向けのリポジトリが見つかったので、こちらも参照してみるとよいかもしれません。
(ただしバージョンは v2.13.1 と古いものになっています)

https://github.com/moonpyk/eccodes-build-windows

Comment: cubickさん @kunif さん、質問か回答どちらにコメントするか悩みましたがこちらに。 Windowsに対応していないのはそうかもしれませんが、ビルドできないのは別問題かなと。その上で [README.md](https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes/tree/master#readme) には **Windows: master passing** のバッジが付いており、ソースコードそのままでビルドできるはずです。であればバッジの根拠となっているAppVeyorのCI手順を確認すればいいのでは、と。（まぁビルドできたとしても使えないかもよ、という警告としてはこの回答にも意味があるかもしれませんが）